# Check if date is in another dataframe and set a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have given two dataframes

df1:

```
    DATE     INTERVALL    
0  2017-01-01  00:30:00.000      
1  2017-01-01  01:00:00.000  
2  2017-01-01  01:30:00.000   
3  2017-01-01  02:00:00.000      
4  2017-01-01  02:30:00.000
....
200 2017-05-09 00:30:00.000
201 2017-05-09 01:00:00.000  
202 2017-05-09 01:30:00.000  
203 2017-05-09 02:00:00.000
....
```

df2:

```
Name                         Date                       
Neujahr                     2017-01-01
Karfreitag                  2017-04-14
Ostersonntag                2017-04-16
Ostermontag                 2017-04-17
1. Mai                      2017-05-01
Christi Himmelfahrt         2017-05-25
Pfingstsonntag              2017-06-04
```

i want to have in df1 a new Column with 'HOLIDAY'.
"HOLIDAY" should have the value 1 if the 'DATE' Column is included in df2.

Example:

```
    DATE     INTERVALL        HOLIDAY    
0  2017-01-01  00:30:00.000     1      
1  2017-01-01  01:00:00.000     1
2  2017-01-01  01:30:00.000     1
3  2017-01-01  02:00:00.000     1 
4  2017-01-01  02:30:00.000     1
....
200 2017-05-09 00:30:00.000     0 
201 2017-05-09 01:00:00.000     0
202 2017-05-09 01:30:00.000     0
203 2017-05-09 02:00:00.000     0 
...
```

i tried with a if statement, but thats to slow. I think there is a  better solutions:

```
    if row['DATE'] == "2017-01-01":
        df1.set_value(index, 'HOLIDAY', 1)
```

Comment: Do you have any code already that you can show us?

Comment: @avix yes, i did an edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with converting `boolean mask` to `True` to `1` and `False` to `0` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
#convert to datetimes if necessary
df1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

df1['HOLIDAY'] = df1['DATE'].isin(df2['Date']).astype(int)
print (df1)
          DATE     INTERVALL  HOLIDAY
0   2017-01-01  00:30:00.000        1
1   2017-01-01  01:00:00.000        1
2   2017-01-01  01:30:00.000        1
3   2017-01-01  02:00:00.000        1
4   2017-01-01  02:30:00.000        1
200 2017-05-09  00:30:00.000        0
201 2017-05-09  01:00:00.000        0
202 2017-05-09  01:30:00.000        0
203 2017-05-09  02:00:00.000        0
```

Detail:

```
print (df1['DATE'].isin(df2['Date']))
0       True
1       True
2       True
3       True
4       True
200    False
201    False
202    False
203    False
Name: DATE, dtype: bool

print (df1['DATE'].dtype)
datetime64[ns]

print (df2['Date'].dtype)
datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: f = lambda x, y: htable.ismember_object(x, values)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_func_helper.pxi", line 428, in pandas._libs.hashtable.ismember_object
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'

Comment: What is your pandas version? It seems some old, because I use `0.20.3` and it working perfectly.

Comment: '0.20.3' aswell

Comment: And both columns are datetimes?

Comment: I add to the end of solution test for it.

Comment: Yes, i found out: two datafrmes with the same Column Names doesnt work: df['HOLIDAY'] = df['DATE'].isin(df2['DATE']).astype(int) gives me the error, but i changed the column name from df1 to another one, and now that works..i dont know why